# How to sum arguments of a list of object in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, object, numpy

When I am using numpy, I can sum two 1D array simply by writing:

```
    C = A + B
```

If I have a list of objects, and all the objects in the list are of the same class and all have three arguments (r, v and a). If I want to compute lets say `r = r + v +0.5*a` for all objects in the list:
How do I write this in one line like I would do in *numpy* knowing that all my object are in one list L ?

Something like this I guess ?:

```
    L.r += L.v + 0.5*L.a
```

Comment: This (vectorization) is one of the primary reasons to use numpy over lists in doing arthmetic.  As far as I know, you can't do this in native python without invoking a for loop or list comprehension.  Out of curiousity, why do you want to work outside of numpy for such operations?

Comment: If I use numpy.asarray on a list of object will I be able to vectorization straight on the arguments of the objects on the numpy.array ? It tells me AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'r'

Comment: @Phaune what you need to do is to create 3 numpy arrays, one for each property, do the vectorized operation (which will be much more efficient) and then set the values in  the original list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't survive with two lines:

```
[setattr(item,'r',item.r + item.v + 0.5 * item.a) for item in L]
```

Comment: But I'd really consider @Adam Hughes comment before doing this.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what the output you are looking for.  Are you looking for a list of numbers:

```
[x.r + x.v + .5*x.a for x in L]
```

The summation of those?

```
sum([x.r + x.v + .5*x.a for x in L])
```

Or changing the objects themselves?

```
runningSum=0
def mod(obj):
    # How complicated this function is depends on what your trying to accomplish.  
    obj.r = runningSum + obj.r + obj.v + .5*obj.a
    runningSum = obj.r
    return obj

map(mod,L)
```

Comment: I don't think the question states anything about desired output, the asker just wants to replicate a numpy functionality.

Answer (score 1):

While not a formal answer, I would like to pick up your curiosity and make you imagine a world of possibilities arising from your question. If you don't want to use numpy for some reason, and you just wonder how to make the sum of all elements within a list in just one line, you may want to redefine the operation between lists. This can be achieved by defining a very simple class like the following one:

```
class array():
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        self.list = mylist
        return
    def __add__(self, other):
        for i in xrange(len(self.list)):
            self.list[i] += other.list[i]
        return array(self.list)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.list)
```

You can see that the class is instantiated using a python list, and then I define the `__add__` method, which essentially indicate how the *array* objects interact under the + symbol. Of course, there is plenty of room here to improve it and check for exceptions, but this is only to highlight the fact that you can define whatever you want. You can see that the addition of two array objects returns a new array object, which allow us to keep adding.

Just for you to see how does it work, below I write a very simple example:

```
A = array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = array([3,2,4,5,6])
C = A+B
```

Then if you type C in the prompt, you will see

```
[4, 4, 7, 9, 11]
```

which again is an array class.

Answer (score 0):

If you can survive with two lines try this:

```
for item in L:
    item.r += item.v + 0.5 * item.a
```